# i want to run my application in background and start it when i say some keywords like the name of the app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have search for it a lot but didn't get anything interesting.

I want two things to be done mentioned as below :

1.App should run in background.

2.Should listen what user says ,and if user say like the name "android" ,the app should come in  foreground and run as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done it using service and Alarammanager and when i say some keywords like "android" it starts the Main Activity.

In background RecognitionListener is running with the help of Service